# Fetch specific record from Kafka in Python using KafkaConsumer by filitering the transactions with sessionID

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

**Context:**

We have a requirement where I need to capture a specific transaction using KafkaConsumer library.I use a unique session as key which I obtain from a different tool(let's call as **Feeder** tool) to capture the transaction.

***I run my code immediately once the session is obtained from Feeder.***

**Problem**

I am able to fetch multiple records from Kafka but I don't see the record which I'm trying to filter using the session.

**Code**

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json
SESSION = 'sessionID'
def consumeRecords(topic,group,bootstrapserver,auto_offset_reset,mySession,auto_commit_boolean):
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic,group_id=group,bootstrap_servers=bootstrapserver,auto_offset_reset=auto_offset_reset,enable_auto_commit=auto_commit_boolean)
    consumer.topics()
    consumer.seek_to_beginning()
    try:
        while True:
            print("CALLING POLL")
            records = consumer.poll(timeout_ms=1000)
            print("RETURNED FROM POLL")
            if records:
                for consumedRecord in records.values():
                    for msg in consumedRecord:
                        json_data = json.loads(msg.value.decode('utf-8'))
                        #print(json_data)
                        if 'alias' in json_data.keys() and json_data['alias']=='myServer':

                            current_session = json_data[SESSION]
                            print("SESSION is :" , current_session)
                            if mySession == current_session :
                                print('My record is ', json_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to find any related sessions")
        print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'e-commerce.request'
    KAFKA_GROUP = 'test'
    KAFKA_BROKERS = ['ABC.net:9092', 'DEF:9092']
    auto_commit = False
    consumeRecords(KAFKA_TOPIC,KAFKA_GROUP,KAFKA_BROKERS,'earliest','38l87jondkvnefNW886QMTWVcN6S4my5Y-No167ZzqF',auto_commit)
```

**I'm supposed to print the following json data consumed from Kafka , but my code *doesn't fetch this record and hence prints nothing and runs for infinite time***

```
{'Type': 'request', 'requestID': '2018100819564659-5', 'payload': {'timing': {'startTime': '20181008195624322', 'total': '0.063', 'totalActions': '0', 'jsp': '0.063'}, 'user': {'orgID': '', 'userID': '', 'newComer': 'FALSE', 'helpdeskUserID': '', 'helpdeskUserOrgID': '', 'travelerID': ''}, 'version': '1.0.0', 'client': {'referrer': '', 'ip': ''}, 'url': {'parameters': {'JSESSIONID': '38l87jondkvnefNW886QMTWVcN6S4my5Y-No167ZzqF!430553578!-1652153437'}, 'baseUrl': 'http://server_url', 'path': 'DUMMY', 'method': 'POST'}, 'actions': [{'cumulTiming': '0', 'name': 'OverrideServlet', 'isChained': 'FALSE', 'features': '[GlobalTimeSpent = 0][PRE_RULES = 0][POST_RULES = 0]', 'chainParent': ''}], 'context': {'sessionSize': '12|12', 'fatalError': 'FALSE', 'requestType': 'XML', 'error': [], 'requestedSessionID': '', 'templateName': ''}}, 'Hostname': 'DummyAgain', 'sessionID': '38l87jondkvnefNW886QMTWVcN6S4my5Y-No167ZzqF', 'Site': 'ABCDEFGH', 'ClientId': 1234551515439, 'Epoch': 1539028584353, 'IP': 'A.B.C.D', 'alias': 'myServer', 'SeqNb': 21845, 'Source': 'eCommerce'}
```

Comment: What is the code currently printing, if anything? Have you ran this in a debugger? Can you show that data from the console-consumer command?

Comment: Excuse the code images. I tried to paste the code , but it's losing the indentations and code would paste like a text and difficult to read.
However , pasting the code now!

Comment: @cricket_007 I have updated my problem with complete details.
Code+ what I'm trying to print

Comment: Thanks! Again, have you been able to use a debugger?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes , I use Pycharm for my coding and used the debugger. I get the records but none of them match with the session I'm trying to find.
Could there be any issue with the way I'm consuming the records ??

Comment: If you are able to see the Json payload, then no, the problem is that no producer is sending the data you're looking filtering by. Note: KSQL would simplify having to write Python code to get this information

Comment: We have the process of pushing the logs from our legacy platforms to Kafka to streamline the logs , which makes the process a Producer . 
I could see other logs related to platform 'myServer' but not the log corresponding to my actions.
Is it possible for a Producer to push certain logs but not my log ??

Comment: It's possible, yes, but you would need to capture any errors generated by that process to find out if that's the case